# How to make a textbox accept html tags

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox, validation, html-encode

I have a textbox in my aspx page. The user wants to have the ability to input html tags in the textbox. The only way so far I know to by pass the validation error is set the ValidateRequest to false. I tried couple of other ways:
(1) using Server.HtmlEncode in a javascript like this

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

        var tb = document.getElementById("<%=synopsisTextBox.ClientID%>");
        var value =Server.HtmlEncode(tb.value);
```

But I got compiler error. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

(2) creating my own encode function

```
function escapeHTML (str) 
{ 
   var div = document.createElement('div'); 
   var text = document.createTextNode(str); 
   div.appendChild(text); 
   return div.innerHTML; 
}
```

somehow it didn't work quite well. When I click some button that causes postback in the same page, it gets stuck.

Can anyone tell me if there is a better way to make your textbox accept html tags? Thanks.

Comment: Why do they want to input html tags in this textbox? The proper solution depends on what they are trying to do; you need to carefully think about how the data will be sanitized as well as encoded, especially if untrusted users will ever see this textbox.

Comment: we build this as a tool for internal users.

Comment: have you solved the problem? did you try my solution?

Answer (score 5):

Just disable input validation (for the page only) and make sure you encode input from other textboxes in the page. Input validation is on by default not because it shouldn't be disabled ever but because you should know what you are doing and do it explicitly. This way you are sure to pay attention and do your own input validation.

Comment: +1 Exactly - there is nothing wrong with disabling request validation. It is just on by default to protect you. Turning it off is just saying to ASP.NET "I know what I'm doing, OK?"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **encode html tags and show them on a browser** remember that

```
 <%= Server.HTMLEncode("The paragraph tag: <P>") %>
```

produces the following output:

```
The paragraph tag: &lt;P&gt;
```

that will be displayed by a Web browser as:

```
The paragraph tag: <P>
```

Your trial with Server.HTMLEncode is not working, since it works when data are on the server and need to be encoded before sending to the browses. In your sample, data are on the browser and *request is blocked on validation before being recieved on the server* .

---

If you want **user to edit TextBox and enter html tags**  you can disable this via

```
 <%@ Page validateRequest="false" ...>
```

or in the web.config for your entire application:

```
<system.web>
  <page validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

> Note that this ValidateRequest property is not existing without
>   reason. When you change its default value, insecure input will be
>   accepted. Because of that, you need to validate every user's input to
>   avoid cross-site scripting attacks, like inserting of malicious
>   JavaScript, ActiveX, Flash or HTML

---

Another smart solution is to **replace via javascript text written by user** to make it safe for validation.
`< tag>` , instead of `<tag>` is considered safe!

```
function validateTxt() {
    $("textarea, input[type='text']").change(function () {
      html = $(this).val(); //get the value
      //.replace("a" , "b")  works only on first occurrence of "a"
      html = html.replace(/< /g, "<"); //before: if there's space after < remove
      html = html.replace(/</g, "< "); // add space after <
      $(this).val(html); //set new value
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
      validateTxt();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be checking for malicious code in javascript, this is very easy to get around.  This validation should be done on the server.

Comment: @RyanM I'm not checking malicious code in javascript.. I'm removing it client side, in order to keep server side validation on! So, any try to get javascript around will be blocked on the server...

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you have these following solutions:

- Follow @Stilgar and also use Anti-XSS for encoding.
- Use Textile or BBCode markup language instead of HTML.